# how do i add ext.net dynamical web form control and retrieve its contain value to save in DB.?

Tags: ext.net, dynamic-controls

i want to dynamically add two text box and obtain values from those and display as message ...
please help me though example to demonstrate this scenario where I can learn and apply for my actual problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take alook at those examples

```
 http://examples.ext.net/#/XRender/Basic/Add_Items/

http://examples.ext.net/#/XRender/Basic/New_Window/
```

*those links ,official web site of ext.net.

instead of adding tab or windows ,just change them to TextField.
u can assign unique id for each element added dynamically,and reach those element via Id